# Docusign Quickstart - NoMethodError at first startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docusignapi

I'm trying to setup and launch a Ruby Quickstart project from the DocuSign Documentation : https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/code-launchers/

I filled the form, downloaded the zip containing the code and followed the whole setup, without difficulties.

But when I launch my server and try to access http://localhost:3000/, an error is displayed :

```
NoMethodError in DsCommonController#index
undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #40):              
  def worker
39    configuration = DocuSign_eSign::Configuration.new
40    configuration.host = args[:base_path] <<<< error on this line
41
42  @api_client = DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient.new(configuration)
43  @api_client.set_base_path(args[:base_path])

Rails.root: /Users/*******/Quickstart App-1-ruby
```

And in the terminal :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass

      @host = host.sub(/https?:\/\//, '').split('/').first
                  ^^^^):
  
app/services/e_sign/get_data_service.rb:40:in `worker'
app/services/e_sign/get_data_service.rb:30:in `cfr?'
app/controllers/ds_common_controller.rb:21:in `handle_redirects'
app/controllers/ds_common_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

I followed every step and I'm not sur what i'm doing wrong. Does someone have a tip ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post a code snippet showing where the problem occurs. The information you provided isn't enough. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The error: undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass
Looking at your excecption, it look like you didn't set up a Redirect URI, hence the error message. Below you can find the method description from DocuSign SDK library:

```
# File lib/docusign_esign/configuration.rb, line 159
def host=(host)
  # remove http(s):// and anything after a slash
  @host = host.sub(/https?:\/\//, '').split('/').first
end
```

You can check for further details in the SDK Library:
https://docusign.github.io/docusign-esign-ruby-client/DocuSign_eSign/Configuration.html#method-i-host-3D